# Nodejs MySQL keeps returning the results

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am having this issue where the result of the MySQL query in NodeJS keeps returning the results in the console and I am wondering why is this happenning?

Here is what I have done:

Server.js

```
 app.get("/api/listproduct", (req, res) => {
        db.query("SELECT * FROM products" , (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(result)
                res.send(result);
            }
        }
        )
    })
```

ShowProduct.js

```
   useEffect(async () => {
        const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/listproduct'); 
        console.log(result.data)    
        setProducts(result.data);
      });
```

As you can see that the result are sort of looping to the console as shown here where it was supposed to just return only one set rather than many of the same sets of results.

[image]

What am I missing here and how to solve this? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks

Comment: hi Tomalak, my bad if I have caused you to misunderstand my question. I have edited the question to be clearer. Thanks

Comment: Is this a real question? `console.log` dude!...

Comment: hi Marc, I am new to using MySQL with Nodejs and I have edited the question to be more clear. Thanks

Comment: @Nat Your question is *not* clear. "keeps returning the results in the console" -> `console.log`

Comment: hi marc, my bad. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the Nodejs/MySQL backend, but your frontend React code.

You don't have a dependency array in your `useEffect`, so it's called every time the component is rendered. Since it calls `setState`, it causes a new render, and effectively an infinite loop of renders. If you don't have dependencies for your effect, [add an empty array to make the effect get called only once](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).

```
useEffect(async () => {
  const result = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/listproduct");
  setProducts(result.data);
}, []); // <- that empty array
```

Comment: AKX, thanks a lot, that does solve it. thanks again

Comment: Great lateral debugging.